# ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not working when updating with identical information

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mariadb

I have this column in my table:

```
date_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I noticed that when I try to update the row with the same information, timestamp does not change.

For example, my table (users) is this:

```
+----+-------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | name  | food           | confirmed | signup_date |
+----+-------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | John  | Casserole      | Y         | 2012-04-11 12:46:55  |
|  2 | Sandy | Key Lime Tarts | N         | 2012-04-14 11:02:02  |
+----+-------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
```

When I run this query, everything works fine (`signup_date` updates as expected):

```
UPDATE users SET name = 'new', food = 'new' where id = 1;
```

However, when I run this (inserting exact info), `signup_date` remains the same as the previous one:

```
UPDATE users SET name = 'John', food = 'Casserole' where id = 1;
```

I need help with getting `signup_date` update disregarding whether information is the same or not. Who can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. An auto-updated column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values.

From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE users SET name = 'new', food = 'new',signup_date = Now() where id = 1;
```

Maybe you could try updating the Column with Now()?

Comment: I tried and it works, but I do not want to specify that. I expect it to be updated automatically since I specify in my statement that it should updated.

Comment: Just wanted to add, If you really really want to do it without adding that one column update. look up on `triggers`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I decided to go with `column = current_timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

if the value does not change, it won't trigger the automatic update. you can easily try it yourself.

Answer (score -2):

the MYSQL update query should be as follow

```
ALTER TABLE  users   
CHANGE COLUMN `signup_date` `signup_date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

but i suggest to keep update time field in a different field some thing like "modified_date" so you can keep track of both the sign up date and last modified date

Comment: Good suggestion about adding a separate column but the column definition is not the problem. Defining it with `NULL` is also generally a bad idea because you can't force a current time by setting the column to `NULL`, and erasing timestamp data is rarely useful.